# How to convert a list and it's corresponding attributes to a data frame?

Tags: r

I have a list of sublists in R and each sublist has attribute 'weights'. The list (msets) is given with the dput below.

I am trying to create a data frame from this list which will look similar to the following:

[image: Expected output]

I have tried many things but closest I have got to is to get the first two columns in my expected output (without the last row with NA) (this is from a post in stackexchange itself):

```
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
msetslist <- map(msets, as.data.table)
data <- rbindlist(msetslist, fill = TRUE, idcol = T)
```

If anyone can show me a direction to get the weight column from this list for the corresponding rows, it will be of a great help! Thanks a lot!.

```
msets <- structure(list(`4.1992` = structure(c("3", "13"), weights = c(`3` = 0.361445410141122, 
`13` = 0.638554589858878)), `4.1997` = structure("7", weights = c(`7` = 1)), 
    `6.1973` = structure("13", weights = c(`13` = 1)), `6.1983` = structure(c("4", 
    "13"), weights = c(`4` = 0.48514051162328, `13` = 0.51485948837672
    )), `7.1991` = structure(c("3", "4", "12", "13"), weights = c(`3` = 0.244828251795591, 
    `4` = 0.299557832665169, `12` = 0.176484058719677, `13` = 0.279129856819563
    )), `12.1992` = structure(c("3", "13"), weights = c(`3` = 0.361445410141122, 
    `13` = 0.638554589858878)), `13.2003` = structure(c("3", 
    "12"), weights = c(`3` = 0.404752956538133, `12` = 0.595247043461867
    )), `7.1998` = character(0)), lag = 4, t.var = "year", id.var = "wbcode2", treatment.var = "dem", class = "matched.set", refinement.method = "ps.weight", covs.formula = ~tradewb, match.missing = FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible example with `dput` so that others can test

Comment: Hi @akrun, I edited the question with dput on the list. Please let me know if I should do anything else.

Comment: In the `dput` output, the structure seems to be slightly different than the one you showed in the post with `str` (it is a nested list there).  I just wonder if this example is a correct representation of your original data structure

Comment: Hi, yes it is a nested list. Sorry, I should have been more clear. I had omitted a few lines in the initial post as it was too long. 'msets' Is the list which I am trying to work on.

Comment: Can you edit and post a new dput because when we test a solution on this data, it may not work with your original structure

Comment: Hi I have edited the post, msets is the list from which I am trying to get to the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: Is the `msets` data mimic your original data now

Comment: Yes. msets is the original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
tmp <- Map(cbind, names(msets), msets, lapply(msets, attr, "weights"))

# make sure they all are frames and have the number of columns
(maxncols <- max(sapply(tmp, ncol)))
# [1] 3
tmp <- lapply(tmp, function(tm) as.data.frame(cbind(tm, matrix(rep(NA, maxncols - ncol(tm)), nrow = nrow(tm)))))

data.table::rbindlist(tmp)
#          V1     V2                V3
#      <char> <char>            <char>
#  1:  4.1992      3 0.361445410141122
#  2:  4.1992     13 0.638554589858878
#  3:  4.1997      7                 1
#  4:  6.1973     13                 1
#  5:  6.1983      4  0.48514051162328
#  6:  6.1983     13  0.51485948837672
#  7:  7.1991      3 0.244828251795591
#  8:  7.1991      4 0.299557832665169
#  9:  7.1991     12 0.176484058719677
# 10:  7.1991     13 0.279129856819563
# 11: 12.1992      3 0.361445410141122
# 12: 12.1992     13 0.638554589858878
# 13: 13.2003      3 0.404752956538133
# 14: 13.2003     12 0.595247043461867
# 15:  7.1998   <NA>              <NA>
```

And from here, column-names and conversion to `numeric` should be straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was trying with rbindlist but was unsuccessful. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

We loop over the `list` with `map`, extract the values in a `tibble` as 'ID2' and the 'weights' `attr`ibutes in 'Weight' column, specify the `.id` as 'ID' (create a new column with the `names` of the `list`) and convert the `list` to single dataset with `_dfr` (row binding).  If needed, convert the column types automatically with `type.convert` (from `base R`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(msets, ~ tibble(ID2 = .x, Weight = attr(.x, "weights")), .id = 'ID') %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
#      ID   ID2 Weight
#   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1  4.20     3  0.361
# 2  4.20    13  0.639
# 3  4.20     7  1    
# 4  6.20    13  1    
# 5  6.20     4  0.485
# 6  6.20    13  0.515
# 7  7.20     3  0.245
# 8  7.20     4  0.300
# 9  7.20    12  0.176
#10  7.20    13  0.279
#11 12.2      3  0.361
#12 12.2     13  0.639
#13 13.2      3  0.405
#14 13.2     12  0.595
```

---

If we need to get those ID with 0 `length`, an option is also

```
map_dfr(msets, ~ if(length(.x)  > 0) tibble(ID2 = .x, 
   Weight = attr(.x, "weights")) else (tibble(ID2 = NA_character_)), 
        .id = 'ID') %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
#     ID   ID2 Weight
#   <dbl> <int>  <dbl>
# 1  4.20     3  0.361
# 2  4.20    13  0.639
# 3  4.20     7  1    
# 4  6.20    13  1    
# 5  6.20     4  0.485
# 6  6.20    13  0.515
# 7  7.20     3  0.245
# 8  7.20     4  0.300
# 9  7.20    12  0.176
#10  7.20    13  0.279
#11 12.2      3  0.361
#12 12.2     13  0.639
#13 13.2      3  0.405
#14 13.2     12  0.595
#15  7.20    NA NA
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! I accepted the other answer as it gives also the element for which the weight and ID2 is missing.

Comment: @econbuffin2019 that's okay. Thank you for specifying the issue

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun! Great to have the option to do this from this answer too!